# Где в приложении будет правильнее разместить список, который хранит состояние?

Tags: spring, mvc, архитектура

Есть список идентификаторов (строки), который обновляется раз в сутки на освновании длительной последовательности действий. Этот список требуется сервису для выполнения некоторой логики.
Ранее этот список извлекался из деплой-конфига 1 раз при старте микросервиса, поэтому был размещен в классе с конфигурацией приложения.

Где теперь будет правильнее хранить этот список? Конфигурационный класс теперь для него не сильно подходит.
Нормально ли будет разместить его, как поле сервиса, в котором он используется?

Comment: Допустимо ли это состояние потерять? Т.е. если произойдет сбой сервера, и перезапуск, то все будет нормально работать?

Comment: Да, все будет работать нормально. В случае перезапуска сервиса автоматически запустится task, в результате исполнения которого этот список, в том числе, будет наполнен вновь.

Answer (score 0):

Разумно ли изменять код сервиса каждый раз, когда нужно поменять список идентификаторов ? Нет, нужно держать такие данные в файле\базе\окружении. Если эти идентификаторы меняются так часто, то проще их с файла брать (но не каждый раз, а кешировать в поле). А то если с базы брать, то эти идентификаторы  в миграцию не добавишь, не удобно...